# How to input hex color to embed message via discord user

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to input via discord user hex color to put in after in to embed message, but he understands it like string, how can I do it ? Now I have code when I created new variable for color, to much code.

```
@client.command()
async def embed(ctx):
    embed_question = discord.Embed(
        title="Enter a title of embed message: ",
        description="||This request will be canceled in 10 seconds!||"
    )
    embed1 = await ctx.send(embed=embed_question)
    try:
        msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=10)
        msg_color = await client.wait_for("message", check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=10)
        r = msg_color.content.split(",", 3)[0]
        g = msg_color.content.split(",", 3)[1]
        b = msg_color.content.split(",", 3)[2]
        embed_question_answer = discord.Embed(
            title=msg.content.split("|", 1)[0],
            description=msg.content.split("|", 1)[1],
            color=discord.Color.from_rgb(int(r), int(g), int(b))
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=embed_question_answer)
        await msg_color.delete()
        await msg.delete()
        await embed1.delete()
        await ctx.message.delete()
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        timeout_embed = discord.Embed(
            title="",
            description="***Cancelling due to timeout.***",
            color=0x2f3136
        )
        await ctx.send(embed=timeout_embed, delete_after=5)
        await msg.delete()
        await embed1.delete()
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the [`commands.ColourConverter`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.ColourConverter) class. although it's a converter meant to be used in typehints, you can just call the convert method to do the same thing.

```py
conv = commands.ColourConverter()
colour_object = await conv.convert(ctx, '#ffffff')
```

Here, the `conv` variable is optional. the #ffffff can be anything, even a variable, even msg_color.content. it accepts colors in lots of formats that you can see in the docs, here is a screenshot if you're too lazy:
[image: screenshot]

As you can see this raises [`commands.BadArgument`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.BadArgument) if the conversion failed. you may wanna catch that too and notify the user that the color they sent is invalid